# Is there a Run all cell below button in 2021 insiders vscode's jupyter extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

So as the title says, in the insider version of vscode's jupyter notebook [I can run all cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCdMt.png) but [unlike the stable vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilG60.png), it seems like I can't run all cells below in the insider version. I was wondering if there was a way to do it or add it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a developer on the VS Code Jupyter extension. We have implemented "Run cell and below", and it will become available in the February release of the Jupyter extension (in the next couple of weeks). Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Okay, i'll wait the update :) Thanks for your answer and effort

Comment: is it available now? i don't see the menu even in latest update of vs code. or i am missing something.

Comment: ok it is an icon `execute cell and below` in code cells small toolbar